# In onActivityResult intent.getSerializableExtra is not calling

Tags: android, list, android-intent, serialization, onactivityresult

> I am not getting OnActivityResult.This method is not calling when I return seriazable list from my second activity.Pls check below code,if I made any mistake pls let me now`

`

> List Activity

```
professional_filter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent  = new Intent(ProfessionalListActivity.this, ProfessionalFilter.class);
                intent.putExtra("data_list", (Serializable)professionalDataList);


                startActivityForResult(intent, PROFESSIONAL_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE);

                startActivity(intent);



            }
        });



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
// super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

    if (requestCode == PROFESSIONAL_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE) {

        intent = getIntent();

        ProfessionalDataList professionalD

ataList = (ProfessionalDataList)
       intent.getSerializableExtra("data_list");
            professionalListAdapter = new 
            ProfessionalListAdapter(ProfessionalListActivity.this, 
           (List<ProfessionalDataList>) professionalDataList, false);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(professionalListAdapter);
            isGrid = true;
            professionalListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
    }
> Filter Activity
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    professionalDataList= (List<ProfessionalDataList>)  
    getIntent().getSerializableExtra("data_list");
     }

> From api response am saving data.If api
```

call is successful I need to pass this data to list activity and update my recycler list.But now am not getting data and list is not updating

```
   Intent intent = new    
   Intent(ProfessionalFilter.this,ProfessionalListActivity.class);     
     intent.putExtra("data_list", (Serializable)  professionalDataList); 
     setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
     startActivity(intent);
     finish();
```

Comment: `Intent intent = new    
   Intent(ProfessionalFilter.this,ProfessionalListActivity.class);     
` Change to `Intent intent = new Intent();`. (And as said before: remove startActivity).

Comment: And first try with returning a simple string. Dont make it so complicated.

Comment: `intent = getIntent();` My god... Remove that! So was onActivityResult invoked but you did not get your data back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove  startActivity(intent) like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();     
intent.putExtra("data_list", (Serializable)  professionalDataList); 
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Hi here first time my filter activity not finishing,2 nd time only its finishing..And at that time onActivity result called but am getting null list

Comment: did you remove startActivity() ?

Comment: yes removed.When I removed startActivity,its not redirecting to List page

Comment: hi I will update my new code,i think I did mistake in somewhere else..Thanks for your help..really appreciate it

Comment: ProfessionalDataList professionalDataList = (ProfessionalDataList) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("dqata_list");//Here am facing issue now.not getting response .list getting as null